# Find next element of an array using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have one array like this.

```
var myArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
```

I need to find the next element when I click next. Suppose I've 2 in a variable, when I click "next" button, I need to check the array and get 3 and so on.

Comment: What have you tried till now? Do you have any partially/non-working script?

Comment: How does your html look like?

Comment: what you think about `loop`??

Comment: what's the problem with `myArray[var]` ?

Comment: There's no need for JQuery. Use plain JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**jQuery:**

You should use [`.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/) with modulus operator:

```
var myArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
var val = "2";
var next = myArray[($.inArray(val, myArray) + 1) % myArray.length];
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/9CGqT/)**

**JavaScript:**

```
var myArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
var val = "2";
var index = myArray.indexOf(val);
if(index >= 0 && index < myArray.length - 1){
   var next = myArray[index + 1];
   alert(next);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/9CGqT/1/)**

Comment: Thanks.. But, when I give 5, it should not show anything.. Because thats the end of the array.. Could you please check it?

Comment: Why have you used modulus in the first place?

Comment: When I print using $.each(mySqllist, function(index, value){
    console.log("Index::"+index+" Value is:"+value);    
   }); It gives me the list of values inside it.. But, when I use your code, it gives me -1 as index value

Comment: @RupamDatta: If you try to get next element of your last element in array. It will show `undefined` if you use modulus it will go back to first element. Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Its working fine check both http://jsfiddle.net/9CGqT/2/ and http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/9CGqT/3/

Comment: Initially I used mySqlList = new Array() and then I changed to [].. still not working

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="next" id="next">

<script>
    var globle = 0; // by default first page
    var myArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#next").click(function(){
            if(globle == myArray.length){
                 globle = 0;
            }

            alert(myArray[globle]);
            globle++;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
var val = "2";
function checknext() {
       var next = $.inArray(val, myArray) + 1;
       if (next < myArray.length) {
            val = myArray[next];
            alert(val);
       }
       else {
           alert("No More Item Exist");
       }
  }

  function checkprv() {                
       var prv = $.inArray(val, myArray) - 1;
         if (prv >= 0) {
           val = myArray[prv];
           alert(val);
         }
         else {
           alert("No More Item Exist");
         }
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4Fj7s/2/)

Comment: Thanks Ishan for your answer